# Boobtbox dialog closes when clicked and the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, c#, dialog, bootbox

I recently change the code of a page that I had in a html page to an aspx one because I needed to implement a master page. The code and the function worked perfectly fine in the htmlpage but since I had changed it to the aspx page the bootbox dialog stop working properly, as soon as I click on it, it closes immediately and refreshes the page. These are the scripts that Im using.

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootbox.js"></script>
```

Here are some of the functions of the page:

```
function disableTool(Herramientaid) {
            bootbox.confirm({
                message: "¿Estas seguro que deseas eliminar este herramienta?",
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: 'Si',
                        className: 'btn-success'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'No',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    }
                },
                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        sendRequest('DisableTool', { "Herramientaid": Herramientaid },
                            function (response) {
                                if (response[0] == 'OK') {
                                    gettool();
                                    bootbox.alert('La herramienta se ha eliminado');
                                }
                                else {
                                    bootbox.alert('Error! ' + response[0]);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function UpdateTool(ToolControl) {
            var Herramientaid = $(ToolControl).parent().parent().find('td').eq(0).html();
            var NombreH = $(ToolControl).parent().parent().find('td').eq(1).html();
            var Adminid = $(ToolControl).parent().parent().find('td').eq(2).html();
            var HDesc = $(ToolControl).parent().parent().find('td').eq(3).html();
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: "Actualizar herramientas",
                message: '<div class="row">  ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="txNombreH">Nombre:</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-9"> ' +
                    '<input type="text" id="txNombreH" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" value=""' + NombreH + '/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="txAdminid">ID del Administrador:</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-9"> ' +
                    '<input type="text" id="txAdminid" class="form-control" placeholder="Administrador ID" value=""' + Adminid + '/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="txHDesc">Descripcion de la herramienta:</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-9"> ' +
                    '<input type="text" id="txHDesc" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion" value=""' + HDesc + '/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>',
                buttons: {
                    No: {
                        label: "No",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function () {

                        }
                    },
                    Yes: {
                        label: "Si",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                            var newNombreH = $('#txNombreH').val();
                            var newAdminid = $('#txAdminid').val();
                            var newHDesc = $('#txHDesc').val();
                            sendRequest('UpdateTool', {
                                "Herramientaid": Herramientaid, "NombreH": newNombreH, "Adminid": newAdminid, "HDesc": newHDesc
                            },
                                function (response) {
                                    if (response[0] == 'OK') {
                                        gettool();
                                        bootbox.alert('Se ha configurado la herramienta');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        UpdateTool(ToolControl);
                                        bootbox.alert('Error! ' + response[0]);
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today, updating to latest and greatest bootbox didn't help. I eventually tracked down that the button click for "Close", "Ok", even "Esc" was triggering the submission of the form event.

I've had to add a propagation catcher after calling my dialog:

```
$(".dialog-class-name").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It feels hacky, but it doesn't involve editing the actual library, and it does work....

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm gonna try that

Comment: That's not something Bootbox should be doing - none of the generated markup for any of the built-in functions includes a submit button. I'd be more inclined to think that something like the code in the question seems to be duplicating IDs from the page, and if this is WebForms and any of those controls have `AutoPostback="true"`, _that_ could be triggering a page update.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the problem definitely was caused by the fact that the code was inside a WebForms.